# GC heap sizing and program memory overhead

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, overhead, heap-size

I'm trying to figure out what's happening with my application.

Problems:

- GC invoking doesn't reduce unused heap size as much as it should, but it should since I'm using serial GC (or UseParNewGC) and agressive heap ratios.
- The program's memory in use is always a lot bigger than the current used and unused heap, too much in my opinion even with other JVM memory included + heap

Command line used:

```
java -XX:+UseSerialGC -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=5 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=10 -Xmx2500M -cp XXXXXX.jar xxxx.xxxx.xxxx
pause
```

*tried with UseParNewGC, same results*

System:
Win7 SP1
4GB RAM + 4GB swapfile
2.99GHZ
Java 1.7 + JDK 1.7

Please see picture to make things more clear:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3sxw.jpg

Comment: What are you trying to   achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than set free ratios, try to set the `New Generation` to a size that enables the short-lived objects to die. Trying to promote as few as possible to the `Old Generation`.

Bear in mind that larges `Young Generation` turns into large collections.

Then set the max `Old Generation` to a size that does not take too long to full `GC` but does not constantly runs them.